# What are the differences between formulating a response in speech vs. formulating a written response?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, writing, speech, speech-comprehension

I am specifically interested in the difference between these two processes during producing a response to a question. What are the differences of the cognitive process between those two scenarios?

I hypothesize that writing requires more iterations in the thought process but couldn't find an answer to this question.